# "Норм чувак" meaning

Tags: значения, выражения, сленг

I had known "чувак," but recently ran into "норм чувак" and was a bit lost, and neither Multitran nor russki-mat.net helped. It sounds to me like some kind of stoner cri-du-coeur. Could someone explain it, especially "норм"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it a `Норм чувак` **(1)** or `Норм, чувак` **(2)** (the latter has comma, which means addressing to `чувак`)?

In a first variant `Норм` is a short form of `нормальный` (`acceptable`, `satisfactory`, `good`), the second one is a short form of `нормально` (`it is ok`).

So, **(1)** may be translated as `He is good dude` in context of mentioning someone. And **(2)** may be translated as `It is ok dude`.

BUT! :) When someone chats with you via IM/SMS, then to shorten his/her phrase (or just due to the laziness) comma might be skipped and `Норм, чувак` may be written as `Норм чувак`. :) And you can guess this only from the context.

Hope I didn't confuse you. :)

Comment: @SAH If you with your friend were speaking about the third person, it is **(1)**, if you were speaking about your plans, events in the past, planned shopping and so on - it is **(2)**.

Comment: First meaning never used in regular conversion, unless with `всё` - `Всё норм чувак` or `Да всё норм чувак` in some cases

Answer (score 4):

It's a contraction of *нормально* ("okay, alright"). The phrase means "it's OK dude".

It's the same phenomenon as "totesing" in English (contracting words so that you get "totes", "sis", "appreesh" etc.)